# Python: {"errors":{"":["Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type '

Tags: python, sql, arrays, json, api

My dict format data `json_output` is like this in Python:

```
[{'code': 'Z0001001',
  'dateList': [{'FDate': '2008-01-11T00:00:00', 'value': 308.7931034482759},
   {'FDate': '2008-01-18T00:00:00', 'value': 308.7931034482759},
   {'FDate': '2008-01-25T00:00:00', 'value': 308.7931034482759},
   {'FDate': '2008-01-31T00:00:00', 'value': 308.7931034482759},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-08T00:00:00', 'value': 309.82758620689657},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-15T00:00:00', 'value': 309.82758620689657},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-22T00:00:00', 'value': 309.82758620689657},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-29T00:00:00', 'value': 309.82758620689657},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-07T00:00:00', 'value': 323.9655172413793},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-14T00:00:00', 'value': 323.9655172413793},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-21T00:00:00', 'value': 323.9655172413793},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-31T00:00:00', 'value': 323.9655172413793},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-11T00:00:00', 'value': 324.48275862068965},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-18T00:00:00', 'value': 324.48275862068965},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-25T00:00:00', 'value': 324.48275862068965},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-30T00:00:00', 'value': 324.48275862068965},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-09T00:00:00', 'value': 326.2068965517241},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-16T00:00:00', 'value': 326.2068965517241},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-23T00:00:00', 'value': 326.2068965517241},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-30T00:00:00', 'value': 329.3333333333333}]},
 {'code': 'Z0001002',
  'dateList': [{'FDate': '2008-01-11T00:00:00', 'value': 294.2857142857143},
   {'FDate': '2008-01-18T00:00:00', 'value': 294.2857142857143},
   {'FDate': '2008-01-25T00:00:00', 'value': 294.2857142857143},
   {'FDate': '2008-01-31T00:00:00', 'value': 294.2857142857143},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-08T00:00:00', 'value': 297.14285714285717},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-15T00:00:00', 'value': 297.14285714285717},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-22T00:00:00', 'value': 297.14285714285717},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-29T00:00:00', 'value': 297.14285714285717},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-07T00:00:00', 'value': 307.14285714285717},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-14T00:00:00', 'value': 307.14285714285717},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-21T00:00:00', 'value': 307.14285714285717},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-31T00:00:00', 'value': 307.14285714285717},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-11T00:00:00', 'value': 309.2857142857143},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-18T00:00:00', 'value': 309.2857142857143},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-25T00:00:00', 'value': 309.2857142857143},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-30T00:00:00', 'value': 309.2857142857143},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-09T00:00:00', 'value': 309.2857142857143},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-16T00:00:00', 'value': 309.2857142857143},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-23T00:00:00', 'value': 309.2857142857143},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-30T00:00:00', 'value': 309.2857142857143}]}]
```

Then I use `json.dumps()` to convert it to json format so that I can transfor json data into SQL server by api.

```
data_json = json.dumps(json_output)

from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
url = "http://xxx/api/xxx"
r_json = requests.post(url, data_json,headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'},auth=HttpNegotiateAuth())
print(r_json)
print(r_json.text)
print(r_json.status_code)
print(r_json.raise_for_status())
```

However, when I ran it, it gave me error like this:

```
{"errors":{"":["Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ZSFund.DataService.Web.Models.Code.CodeValueMaintainEntity' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
```

I tried to transfor them one by one, like just transforring `Z0001001` into SQL once a time, formatting like this:

```
{'code': 'Z0001001',
  'dateList': [{'FDate': '2008-01-11T00:00:00', 'value': 308.7931034482759},
   {'FDate': '2008-01-18T00:00:00', 'value': 308.7931034482759},
   {'FDate': '2008-01-25T00:00:00', 'value': 308.7931034482759},
   {'FDate': '2008-01-31T00:00:00', 'value': 308.7931034482759},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-08T00:00:00', 'value': 309.82758620689657},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-15T00:00:00', 'value': 309.82758620689657},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-22T00:00:00', 'value': 309.82758620689657},
   {'FDate': '2008-02-29T00:00:00', 'value': 309.82758620689657},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-07T00:00:00', 'value': 323.9655172413793},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-14T00:00:00', 'value': 323.9655172413793},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-21T00:00:00', 'value': 323.9655172413793},
   {'FDate': '2008-03-31T00:00:00', 'value': 323.9655172413793},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-11T00:00:00', 'value': 324.48275862068965},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-18T00:00:00', 'value': 324.48275862068965},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-25T00:00:00', 'value': 324.48275862068965},
   {'FDate': '2008-04-30T00:00:00', 'value': 324.48275862068965},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-09T00:00:00', 'value': 326.2068965517241},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-16T00:00:00', 'value': 326.2068965517241},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-23T00:00:00', 'value': 326.2068965517241},
   {'FDate': '2008-05-30T00:00:00', 'value': 329.3333333333333},}]}
```

it showed all okay and nothing wrong, so I guess the array or the list something might be wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you have an extra closing bracket `},}]},` before `Z0001002`. Try changing to `}]},`

Comment: @thorntonc My bad, it's an edit error, I've corrected it. Problem's stll there.

Comment: Does this work?  `r_json = requests.post(url, json_output,headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'},auth=HttpNegotiateAuth())`  The call to `post()` is expecting a list or dict and will serialize `json_output` to json for you.

Comment: @MikeOrganek It doesn't work. The feedback is ```<Response [400]>
{"errors":{"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '', line 0, position 0."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|e91ae74a-4998ab96d1d19138."}``` .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Asked adminstrators about the post problem, the answer is "SQL Server now are unable to input a Json array data, instead, should do it in a for-loop one by one." In this example, it is:

```
for i in json_output：
    data_json = json.dumps(i)
    url = "http://xxx/api/xxx"
    r_json = requests.post(url, data_json,headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'},auth=HttpNegotiateAuth())
    print(r_json)
    print(r_json.text)
    print(r_json.status_code)
    print(r_json.raise_for_status())
```

And It works good.